# Why attribute selected in <select><option> don't work with ngModel?

Tags: html, angular6, html-select, angular-ngmodel

I have a problem with Angular 6: if I use a component based on the `<select>` element (combo-box), if I use it with the classic way, everything works (notice that I used the `selected` attribute: the result is that in the template the default option already appears as selected, as I would expect!):

```
<select data-width="200px" title="title" name = "name"
>
  <option value='default' selected>Default</option>
  <option value='1'>Value 1</option>
  <option value='2'>Value 2</option>
</select>
```

[image]

The problem is that if I use the `[(ngModel)]` directive (
it needs me necessarily to get the value entered in the combo box), for some reason the selected attribute does not seem to work anymore and the combo box appears with an empty value as the `selected` option.

```
<select data-width="200px" title="title" name = "name"
        [(ngModel)] = "value"
>
  <option value='default' selected>Default</option>
  <option value='1'>Value 1</option>
  <option value='2'>Value 2</option>
</select>
```

[image]

This is certainly not the behavior I would like to have a default option selected preserving the `ngModel` directive.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can't you set `value` to 'default' ? And then you can get rid of `selected` element's attribute.

Answer (score 3):

because Angular doesn't rely on `selected` to check the value.

`ngModel` bind your HTML element to an actual value : if you want to select a value by default, your `ngModel` has to be equal to that value.

So, in your component, you should have

```
value = 'default'; // or '1' or '2'
```

So that Angular fetches the correct option in your select.