# Strange behavior of <select> component with ngModel

Tags: html, angular6, components, html-select, ngmodel

I'm developing a web application using Angular 6. if I create a custom component that simulates the HTML `<select>`, I can not make it have a default value when it is referenced by another component!
You can find the (simple) application code at the following link: [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dw2xot?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630274/angular-6-why-attribute-selected-in-selectoption-dont-work-with-ngmodel?noredirect=1#comment94119996_53630274) 
I asked how to set a default value when the `ngModel` is present (
the `selected` attribute of `<option>` doesn't work anymore!). 
As you can see my `input-select` custom component 
initialize `value` (value linked to the ngModel).

```
value: any = 'default';
```

Unfortunately, however, the component is displayed like this:

[image]

As you can see the console, at the press of submit, print this:

[image]

I would like this situation not to show up: I would like a combo box with a pre-selected value. I can't understand what I was wrong with this application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had used `ngModel` but did not bind with anything so Angular doesn't know what value it supposed to bind with. You should bind `ngModel` with `property` which contains the default value.

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
  <input-select
  name="name"
  [options]="my_options"
  [(ngModel)]="value"
  ></input-select>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Working copy is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qanpuu